# Set indeterminate property of checkbox in jQuery on dynamic creation in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a set of dynamic checkboxes in Cheetah template (that in turn uses python dictionary to create these).

I have emulated a tristate behavior for these checkboxes by associating a function onChange in jQuery. It works correctly once the page is loaded. But unable to get it working for the first load of page. For ex, if a checkbox is selected in the subgroup, the parent is not set to indeterminate state. Similarly, if all checkboxes are selected "select all" option isn't checked.

How do I trigger the function on dynamic creation?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //jQuery functions to handle all actions for the widget
  //This code handles enabling the checkboxes for children belonging to 
  //a particular parent based on the attribute "group". The parent checkbox
  //behavior is emulated for children.
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("group").indexOf("group") >= 0) {
      groupid = $(this).attr("group").split("_")[1]
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.child' + groupid + '> input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
          $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
      } else {
        $('.child' + groupid + '> input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
          $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });
      }
    } else if ($(this).attr("group").indexOf("child") >= 0) {
      //Implementation for tristate behavior for inner level children list.
      //The parent checkbox's state is changed according to child's state change.
      //It can be one of the following:selected, unselected and indeterminate.
      var checkboxlength = $(this).parent().parent().find(
          '.childCheckbox').length,
        checkall2 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.parent').find(
          '.parentCheckbox'),
        selcheckboxlength = $(this).parent().parent().find(
          '.childCheckbox:checkbox:checked').length;

      checkall2.prop("checked", false);
      checkall2.prop("indeterminate", false);

      checkall2.prop("checked", checkboxlength == selcheckboxlength);
      checkall2.prop("indeterminate", checkboxlength != selcheckboxlength && selcheckboxlength > 0);
    } else {
      return;
    }
    
    //Handle the tristate behavior for select all function (including parents and children).
    var checkall = $('#select_all'),
      allParentCheckboxlength = $(document).find('input.parentCheckbox')
      .length,
      selParentcheckboxlength = $(document).find(
        'input.parentCheckbox:checked').length;
      indetrmntParentlength = $(document).find(
        'input.parentCheckbox:indeterminate').length;
      //alert(indetrmntParentlength);
        checkall.prop("checked", false);
        checkall.prop("indeterminate", false);

        checkall.prop("checked", allParentCheckboxlength == selParentcheckboxlength);
        checkall.prop("indeterminate", indetrmntParentlength != 0 || allParentCheckboxlength != selParentcheckboxlength && selParentcheckboxlength != 0);        
  });
});

//Expand or collapse the div according to arrow click for children of a particular parent.
$(document).on('click', '.deviceArrow.closedDiv', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".childContainer").show();
  $(this).removeClass("closedDiv").addClass('openedDiv');
});
$(document).on('click', '.deviceArrow.openedDiv', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".childContainer").hide();
  $(this).removeClass("openedDiv").addClass('closedDiv');
});

//Collapse all collapses all children divs open and displays only parent.
$(document).on('click', '.collapseAll', function() {
  $(document).find(".fileGroupTable").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".childContainer").hide();
    $(this).find(".parent .deviceArrow").removeClass("openedDiv").addClass(
      'closedDiv');
  });
});

//Expand all expands children of each parent.
$(document).on('click', '.expandAll', function() {
  $(document).find(".fileGroupTable").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".childContainer").show();
    $(this).find(".parent .deviceArrow").removeClass("closedDiv").addClass(
      'openedDiv');
  });
});

//Reset unchecks every checkbox contained in the div.
$(document).on('click', '#reset', function() {
  $('#select_all').prop("checked", false);
  setCheckBoxes(false);
});

//Change parent and children checkbox state if select all is changes.
$(document).on('change', '#select_all', function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    setCheckBoxes(true);
  } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
    setCheckBoxes(false);
  }
});

//Fucntion to set checkboxes (both parent and children) to a value sent in parameter.
function setCheckBoxes(setValue) {
  $('.fileGroupTable').find('.eachFileGroupDiv .childContainer').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", setValue);
  });
  $('.fileGroupTable').find('.eachFileGroupDiv .parent').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", setValue);
  });
}
```

```css
.child, .child1,.child2,.child3{
 padding-left: 40px;
}
.parent{
 font-weight:bold;
}
.openedDiv::before {
    content: "V";
    font-weight: bold;

}

.body{
 padding: 20px;
 margin-left: 10px; 
}
.closedDiv::before {
    content: ">";
    display: inline-block;
}
.openedDiv, .closedDiv {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 4px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.openedDiv, .closedDiv {
    color: #bbbbbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.fileGroupActions{
 padding:10px;
 width:440px;
}

.fileGroupTable{
 padding:10px;
 height: auto;
 width:450px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.fileGroupActionsSpan{
 margin-left: 13px;
}

.expandAll{
 padding: 5px;
 margin-left: 45px;
}

.collapseAll{
 padding: 5px;
}

.reset{
 float:right;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
<div id="file_group_actions" class="fileGroupActions">
 <span class="fileGroupActionsSpan fileGroupActions">
  <input type="checkbox" group="none" id="select_all"> Select All
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='expandAll'> Expand All</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='collapseAll'> Collapse All</a>
  <input type="button" value="Reset" class="reset" id="reset">
 </span>
</div>
<div id="file_group_table" class=fileGroupTable>
 <div class="eachFileGroupDiv">
  <div class="parent" id="parent_1">
   <i id="test1" class="deviceArrow openedDiv"></i>
   <input group="group_1" id="test1" class="parentCheckbox" type="checkbox"> Archived and compressed
  </div>
  <div id="child_container_1" class="childContainer">
   <div class="child1">
    <input group="child_1" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked="true"> jar
   </div>
   <div class="child1">
    <input group="child_1" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> war
   </div>
   <div class="child1">
    <input group="child_1" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> vsi
   </div>
   <div class="child1">
    <input group="child_1" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> msu
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="eachFileGroupDiv">
  <div id="parent_2" class="parent" >
   <i class="deviceArrow openedDiv"></i>
   <input group="group_2" class="parentCheckbox" type="checkbox"> Audio and sound
  </div>
  <div id="child_container_2" class="childContainer"> 
   <div class="child2">
    <input group="child_2" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> wpl
   </div>
   <div class="child2">
    <input group="child_2" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> cda
   </div>
   <div class="child2">
    <input group="child_2" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> wma
   </div>
   <div class="child2">
    <input group="child_2" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> snd
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="eachFileGroupDiv">
  <div id="parent_3" class="parent">
   <i class="deviceArrow openedDiv"></i>
   <input group="group_3" class="parentCheckbox" type="checkbox"> Backup
  </div>
  <div id="child_container_3" class="childContainer"> 
   <div class="child3">
    <input group="child_3" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> wbcat
   </div>
   <div class="child3">
    <input group="child_3" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> xlk
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u57k1sto/)

I tried using `.trigger("change")` but it resets all checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to break out you "change"-cod into a function that can be called.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  if ($(e).attr("group").indexOf("group") >= 0) {
    groupid = $(e).attr("group").split("_")[1]
    if ($(e).is(':checked')) {
      $('.child' + groupid + '> input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(e.target).prop("checked", true);
      });
    } else {
      $('.child' + groupid + '> input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(e).prop("checked", false);
      });
    }
  } else if ($(e).attr("group").indexOf("child") >= 0) {
    //Implementation for tristate behavior for inner level children list.
    //The parent checkbox's state is changed according to child's state change.
    //It can be one of the following:selected, unselected and indeterminate.
    var checkboxlength = $(e).parent().parent().find(
        '.childCheckbox').length,
      checkall2 = $(e).parent().parent().parent().find('.parent').find(
        '.parentCheckbox'),
      selcheckboxlength = $(e).parent().parent().find(
        '.childCheckbox:checkbox:checked').length;

    checkall2.prop("checked", false);
    checkall2.prop("indeterminate", false);

    checkall2.prop("checked", checkboxlength == selcheckboxlength);
    checkall2.prop("indeterminate", checkboxlength != selcheckboxlength && selcheckboxlength > 0);
  } else {
    return;
  }

  //Handle the tristate behavior for select all function (including parents and children).
  var checkall = $('#select_all'),
    allParentCheckboxlength = $(document).find('input.parentCheckbox')
    .length,
    selParentcheckboxlength = $(document).find(
      'input.parentCheckbox:checked').length;
  indetrmntParentlength = $(document).find(
    'input.parentCheckbox:indeterminate').length;
  //alert(indetrmntParentlength);
  checkall.prop("checked", false);
  checkall.prop("indeterminate", false);

  checkall.prop("checked", allParentCheckboxlength == selParentcheckboxlength);
  checkall.prop("indeterminate", indetrmntParentlength != 0 || allParentCheckboxlength != selParentcheckboxlength && selParentcheckboxlength != 0);
}
```

Then call this function on `document.ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //jQuery functions to handle all actions for the widget
  //This code handles enabling the checkboxes for children belonging to 
  //a particular parent based on the attribute "group". The parent checkbox
  //behavior is emulated for children.
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i, e){
    console.log(e)
    myFunction(e);
  })

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    myFunction(this);
  })

});
```

Now you can reuse your function if you want. Here is the link to the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u57k1sto/2/)

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you so much.

Comment: There was a minor bug. Children selection for inner list was not working. Updated [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u57k1sto/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use the functions you set up to handle the logic. One way to do this is to just trigger two clicks for each input that is checked. A better way is to probably just use a class or data attribute to trigger a click on whichever input so you don't have to trigger it twice.

Example on line 54: https://jsfiddle.net/yrv8v8po/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //jQuery functions to handle all actions for the widget
  //This code handles enabling the checkboxes for children belonging to 
  //a particular parent based on the attribute "group". The parent checkbox
  //behavior is emulated for children.
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("group").indexOf("group") >= 0) {
      groupid = $(this).attr("group").split("_")[1]
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.child' + groupid + '> input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
          $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
      } else {
        $('.child' + groupid + '> input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
          $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });
      }
    } else if ($(this).attr("group").indexOf("child") >= 0) {
      //Implementation for tristate behavior for inner level children list.
      //The parent checkbox's state is changed according to child's state change.
      //It can be one of the following:selected, unselected and indeterminate.
      var checkboxlength = $(this).parent().parent().find(
          '.childCheckbox').length,
        checkall2 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.parent').find(
          '.parentCheckbox'),
        selcheckboxlength = $(this).parent().parent().find(
          '.childCheckbox:checkbox:checked').length;

      checkall2.prop("checked", false);
      checkall2.prop("indeterminate", false);

      checkall2.prop("checked", checkboxlength == selcheckboxlength);
      checkall2.prop("indeterminate", checkboxlength != selcheckboxlength && selcheckboxlength > 0);
    } else {
      return;
    }

    //Handle the tristate behavior for select all function (including parents and children).
    var checkall = $('#select_all'),
      allParentCheckboxlength = $(document).find('input.parentCheckbox')
      .length,
      selParentcheckboxlength = $(document).find(
        'input.parentCheckbox:checked').length;
      indetrmntParentlength = $(document).find(
        'input.parentCheckbox:indeterminate').length;
      //alert(indetrmntParentlength);
        checkall.prop("checked", false);
        checkall.prop("indeterminate", false);

        checkall.prop("checked", allParentCheckboxlength == selParentcheckboxlength);
        checkall.prop("indeterminate", indetrmntParentlength != 0 || allParentCheckboxlength != selParentcheckboxlength && selParentcheckboxlength != 0);        
  });

  $('.childCheckbox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
      $(this).trigger('click')
      $(this).trigger('click')
    }
  });
});

//Expand or collapse the div according to arrow click for children of a particular parent.
$(document).on('click', '.deviceArrow.closedDiv', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".childContainer").show();
  $(this).removeClass("closedDiv").addClass('openedDiv');
});
$(document).on('click', '.deviceArrow.openedDiv', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".childContainer").hide();
  $(this).removeClass("openedDiv").addClass('closedDiv');
});

//Collapse all collapses all children divs open and displays only parent.
$(document).on('click', '.collapseAll', function() {
  $(document).find(".fileGroupTable").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".childContainer").hide();
    $(this).find(".parent .deviceArrow").removeClass("openedDiv").addClass(
      'closedDiv');
  });
});

//Expand all expands children of each parent.
$(document).on('click', '.expandAll', function() {
  $(document).find(".fileGroupTable").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".childContainer").show();
    $(this).find(".parent .deviceArrow").removeClass("closedDiv").addClass(
      'openedDiv');
  });
});

//Reset unchecks every checkbox contained in the div.
$(document).on('click', '#reset', function() {
  $('#select_all').prop("checked", false);
  setCheckBoxes(false);
});

//Change parent and children checkbox state if select all is changes.
$(document).on('change', '#select_all', function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    setCheckBoxes(true);
  } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
    setCheckBoxes(false);
  }
});

//Fucntion to set checkboxes (both parent and children) to a value sent in parameter.
function setCheckBoxes(setValue) {
  $('.fileGroupTable').find('.eachFileGroupDiv .childContainer').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", setValue);
  });
  $('.fileGroupTable').find('.eachFileGroupDiv .parent').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", setValue);
  });
}
```

```css
.child, .child1,.child2,.child3{
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.parent{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.openedDiv::before {
    content: "V";
    font-weight: bold;

}

.body{
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;  
}
.closedDiv::before {
    content: ">";
    display: inline-block;
}
.openedDiv, .closedDiv {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 4px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.openedDiv, .closedDiv {
    color: #bbbbbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.fileGroupActions{
    padding:10px;
    width:440px;
}

.fileGroupTable{
    padding:10px;
    height: auto;
    width:450px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.fileGroupActionsSpan{
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.expandAll{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.collapseAll{
    padding: 5px;
}

.reset{
    float:right;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
<div id="file_group_actions" class="fileGroupActions">
    <span class="fileGroupActionsSpan fileGroupActions">
        <input type="checkbox" group="none" id="select_all"> Select All
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='expandAll'> Expand All</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='collapseAll'> Collapse All</a>
        <input type="button" value="Reset" class="reset" id="reset">
    </span>
</div>
<div id="file_group_table" class=fileGroupTable>
    <div class="eachFileGroupDiv">
        <div class="parent" id="parent_1">
            <i id="test1" class="deviceArrow openedDiv"></i>
            <input group="group_1" id="test1" class="parentCheckbox" type="checkbox"> Archived and compressed
        </div>
        <div id="child_container_1" class="childContainer">
            <div class="child1">
                <input group="child_1" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked="true"> jar
            </div>
            <div class="child1">
                <input group="child_1" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> war
            </div>
            <div class="child1">
                <input group="child_1" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> vsi
            </div>
            <div class="child1">
                <input group="child_1" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> msu
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="eachFileGroupDiv">
        <div id="parent_2" class="parent" >
            <i class="deviceArrow openedDiv"></i>
            <input group="group_2" class="parentCheckbox" type="checkbox"> Audio and sound
        </div>
        <div id="child_container_2" class="childContainer"> 
            <div class="child2">
                <input group="child_2" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> wpl
            </div>
            <div class="child2">
                <input group="child_2" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> cda
            </div>
            <div class="child2">
                <input group="child_2" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> wma
            </div>
            <div class="child2">
                <input group="child_2" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> snd
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="eachFileGroupDiv">
        <div id="parent_3" class="parent">
            <i class="deviceArrow openedDiv"></i>
            <input group="group_3" class="parentCheckbox" type="checkbox"> Backup
        </div>
        <div id="child_container_3" class="childContainer"> 
            <div class="child3">
                <input group="child_3" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> wbcat
            </div>
            <div class="child3">
                <input group="child_3" class="childCheckbox" type="checkbox"> xlk
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution also worked for me. Thank you. Accepted @Zorken17 's answer as it is cleaner and closer to my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

"Select All" and "Reset" are not working in the selected answer. I was going to comment with an updated jsfiddle, but I'm new. :) Anyway, the "indeterminate" properties of select all and the parents were not getting reset to false, so on select all they were not getting checked/unchecked and on reset they remained indeterminate. Updated code snippets below, and link to the jsFiddle.

```
//Reset unchecks every checkbox contained in the div.
$(document).on('click', '#reset', function() {
  $('#select_all').prop("indeterminate", false);
  $('#select_all').prop("checked", false);
  setCheckBoxes(false);
});

//Function to set checkboxes (both parent and children) to a value sent in parameter.
function setCheckBoxes(setValue) {
  $('.fileGroupTable').find('.eachFileGroupDiv .childContainer').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", setValue);
  });
  $('.fileGroupTable').find('.eachFileGroupDiv .parent').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("indeterminate", false);
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", setValue);
  });
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ano3gztx/)